# ¿Cómo enviar los valores seleccionados de un formulario en HTML?

Tags: html, formularios

Estoy haciendo un formulario en HTML y tengo un pequeño problema. Cuando se envía el form en vez de llegar el texto seleccionado llega el value (1, 2 o 3), pero lo que quiero que se envíe es "da 200€ a 500€".

La selección de los campos es obligatoria. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Código:

````
                           <select type="text" name="Budget a disposizione" placeholder="Budget a disposizione (*)" data-form-field="url" class="form-control" value="" id="url-form5-b" required>
                          <option selected value=""> Budget a disposizione </option> 
                               <option value="1">da 200€ a 500€ </option>
                               <option value="2">da 500€ a 1000€</option>
                               <option value="3">da 1000€ a 2000€</option>
                               <option value="4">più di 2000€</option>
                               <option value="5">Devo ancora definirlo</option>
                           </select> ```
````

Comment: En los formulario html siempre te va a enviar el value.El texto de da X€ a Y€ es para el usuario. Lo que puedes hacer es recuperar el texto según el value que has tenido. Si quieres que te retorne el texto directamente tendría que ir en el value.
Tambien podrias poner un evento de onchange con javascript y actualizando un input hidden

Comment: Si quieres que se envie como quieras entonces reemplaza esos numeros por el texto y respondiendo a tu pregunta, siempre se enviara el `value` de los controles `input,select,etc`. A menos que cambies ese aspecto y decirle que quieres enviar realmente

Answer (score 2):

Te convendría dar una buena lectura a esta [página](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) donde se explica el uso de `<select>` y `<option>`

El valor que des a `value` es el que será enviado al servidor y no el texto que coloques dentro de la etiqueta `<option>`.

Como puedes ver en este ejemplo:

```
<select>
  <option value="Valor que se envía al servidor">Explicación para el usuario</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso Lo que envías al servidor es el valor dentro de la etiqueta value, una solución rápida podría ser la siguiente:

```
 <select type="text" name="Budget a disposizione" placeholder="Budget a disposizione (*)" data-form-field="url" class="form-control" value="" id="url-form5-b" required>
                          <option selected value=""> Budget a disposizione </option> 
                               <option value="200€ a 500€">da 200€ a 500€ </option>
                               <option value="500€ a 1000€">da 500€ a 1000€</option>
                               <option value="1000€ a 2000€">da 1000€ a 2000€</option>
                               <option value="2000€">più di 2000€</option>
                               <option value="5">Devo ancora definirlo</option>
                           </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

El valor que siempre se envia es el que esta en el option, una solucion a tu problema es el siguiente:

```
<select type="text" name="Budget a disposizione" placeholder="Budget a disposizione (*)" data-form-field="url" class="form-control" value="" id="url-form5-b" required>
                      <option selected value=""> Budget a disposizione </option> 
                           <option value="200€ a 500€">da 200€ a 500€ </option>
                           <option value="500€ a 1000€">da 500€ a 1000€</option>
                           <option value="1000€ a 2000€">da 1000€ a 2000€</option>
                           <option value="2000€">più di 2000€</option>
                           <option value="5">Devo ancora definirlo</option>
                       </select>
```

Sin embargo guardar cadenas de texto como lo haces nunca es la mejor manera, si ya manejas bases de datos usa en el value los ID´s